# The explicit expression for integral of forms

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Could anyone please help me with the following three questions? They are simple questions, but I am confused.

1. With a $2$-form $F=\frac{1}{2}F_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}$ in 4 dimension, what is the explicit expression of $\int F\wedge F$ in coordinates? 
   I got something like $$ \int F\wedge F= \frac{1}{4}\int F_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}d^4x.$$
   My question is: How is that $\epsilon$ defined? I found several definitions and they differ from each other by a factor of $\sqrt{|g|}$ infront. If I am going to do it in 4-D spherical coordinate, how does $\epsilon$ look like ?
2. What is the explicit expression of this one in a 3-D coordinate? 
   $$\int_{R^3} d(\phi df\wedge dg)$$ 
   $\phi$, $f$ and $g$ are $0$-form functions. What if I use the Stoke's theorem,
   $$\int_{\partial R^3} \phi df\wedge dg$$ 
   how does it look like explicitly in some coordinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. question**

The totally antisymmetric symbol $\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}$ ($=1$ if indexes not permuted) is not a tensor. Usually, it is just a symbol. The total antisymmetry means that it is antisymmetric in all indexes, meaning that it changes sign to $-1$ if the permutation of indexes is odd, and remains $+1$ if the permutation is even, and it vanishes if any index repeats.

To see how it transforms, we will take a slight detour, and consider how it can be used to define determinants. So, let $\mathbf M^{n\times n}$ denote $n\times n$ matrices over lets say $\mathbb R$, and define $\det:\mathbf M^{n\times n}\to\mathbb R$ such that $$A=(a_{ij})\mapsto \det A := \sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n} \varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}a_{1i_1}a_{2i_2}\cdots a_{ni_n}.$$

To get the transformation law, we will write down this equation differently, and then set $A$ to be the Jacobian of a change of coordinates. This will give us what we need.

Let's use the summation convention from now on. First note that $\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}=n!$, because the number of permutations of a set of $n$ elements is $n!$ - this product of Levi-Civitas will now give 1 whenever there is any permutation, and 0 when it's not, so it just counts the permutations.

Secondly, convince yourself that we could write
$$\det A = \frac{1}{n!}\varepsilon_{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n}\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}a_{j_1i_1}a_{j_2i_2}\cdots a_{j_ni_n}.$$
We are doing the same sum as before, but overcounting by $n!$, hence the factor $1/n!$. Now multiply by $\varepsilon_{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n}$ and sum:
$$\varepsilon_{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n}\det A = \varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}a_{j_1i_1}a_{j_2i_2}\cdots a_{j_ni_n}.$$

Good, now we can see about the $\sqrt{g}$ factors. Put $A=\big(\frac{\partial x_m}{\partial y_n}\big):$

$$\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}\frac{\partial x_{i_1}}{\partial y_{j_1}}\frac{\partial x_{i_2}}{\partial y_{j_2}}\cdots \frac{\partial x_{i_n}}{\partial y_{j_n}}=\det\big(\frac{\partial x_m}{\partial y_n}\big)\varepsilon_{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n}.$$

Therefore, we can't think of $\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}$ as components of some $(0,n)$-tensor $$\varepsilon_{abc\dots} = \sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n} \mathrm d x^{i_1}\otimes \mathrm d x^{i_2}\otimes\dots\otimes\mathrm d x^{i_n}, $$
since it's components transform as $$\varepsilon_{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n}=J^{-1}\varepsilon_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n}\frac{\partial x_{i_1}}{\partial y_{j_1}}\frac{\partial x_{i_2}}{\partial y_{j_2}}\cdots \frac{\partial x_{i_n}}{\partial y_{j_n}}$$ where $J$ is the Jacobian determinant, as before. The Jacobian shouldn't be there for this to be a tensor - the situation we have is that $\varepsilon_{abc\dots}$ is a *tensor density*, which is common enough to have a name! If our space is admits a *metric tensor*, however, we know that in a new basis $$\tilde g\equiv\det\left(  \tilde g_{ab}\right)=\det\left(g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial x_{\mu}}{\partial y_{a}} \frac{\partial x_{\nu}}{\partial y_{b}}\right) \\=\det\left(\frac{\partial x_{\mu}}{\partial y_{a}}\right)\det\left(\frac{\partial x_{\nu}}{\partial y_{b}}\right)\det\left( g_{\mu\nu}\right)= J^2 g.$$

This means that while $\varepsilon$ gets an extra factor of $J^{-1}$, $g$ gets an extra factor of $J^2$. Therefore, the following transforms correctly:

$$e_{abc\dots}:=\sqrt{|g|} \varepsilon_{abc\dots}.$$

Now we raise the indices using the (inverse) metric:

$$e^{j_1\dots j_n}=\sqrt{|g|} g^{i_1 j_1}\cdots g^{i_n j_n}\varepsilon_{i_1\dots i_n}$$
where we use our second definitions for the determinant (but with all indices up!): 
$$e^{j_1\dots j_n}=\sqrt{|g|}\:\frac{1}{g}\:\varepsilon^{j_1\dots j_n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\varepsilon^{j_1\dots j_n}.$$

Therefore, in your question, $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}d^4x$ lacks a factor of $1/\sqrt{|g|}$... **however**, $d^4 x$ lacks a factor of $\sqrt{|g|}$! So the two precisely cancel each other out!

If you are't familiar with the reason the volume element is $\sqrt{|g|} \mathrm d^n x$, it's similar to the above. Because the exerior (wedge) product is totally antisymmetric, exactly like the Levi-Civita, we can write
$$\mathrm d^n x = \mathrm d x^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge\mathrm d x^{i_n}= \frac{1}{n!}\sum \varepsilon_{i_1,\dots,i_n}\mathrm d x^{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\mathrm d x^{i_n} $$
and exactly the same discussion as before implies that the extra factor is needed.

In spherical coordinates, we see that the symbol $\varepsilon$ picks up $J^{-1}$. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element) we can find the Jacobian for n-spherical cooridnates. Moreover, $\varepsilon$ picks up all those derivatives.

**2. question**

I urge you to try this one yourself, it's a really simple exercise, but I'll write it out. Try it before reading! We can write $\mathrm d f$ as $$\mathrm d f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm d x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm d y+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm d z$$
and similarly with $g$, so that

$$\mathrm df\wedge\mathrm d g = \left(f_x g_y - g_x f_y\right) \mathrm d x \wedge \mathrm dy+\left(f_x g_z - g_x f_z\right) \mathrm d x \wedge \mathrm dz+\left(f_y g_z - g_y f_z\right) \mathrm d y \wedge \mathrm dz.$$

$\phi\,\mathrm df\wedge\mathrm d g$ is just this multiplied by $\phi$. Note that your second integral is zero, since $\mathbb R^3$ has no boundary! I don't have time to explicitly calculate the exterior derivative of this, but the result will definitely be very long, and you'll have $(\text{lots of factors involving partial derivatives})\mathrm d x \wedge\mathrm d y\wedge\mathrm d z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! For the second question, I have no problem working in cartesian coordinate. Could you illustrate a bit using spherical coordinate?

Comment: "since $\mathbb R^3$ has no boundary! "  Why is that? Normally, points at the infinities is the boundary. In addition to that, if the differential form or  vector function has some singularities/irregularities, we have to treat those points as boundaries as well.

Comment: @mastrok This is a good question. A *manifold with boundary* is locally like an upper half plane, ie has an atlas ${(U_i,\phi_i)}$ such that $ \phi_i:U_i\to\phi_i(U_i)\subset \mathcal H^n $ where $\mathcal H^n = \{(x^1,\dots,x^n)\in \mathbb R^n | x^n\geq 0\}.$ The boundary itself are locally the points with $x^n=0$. So $\mathbb R^n$ can't have a boundary as it is locally homeomorphic to itself. To think about infinity easier, compactify $R^n$ to $R^n\cup\{\infty\}$, which is the n-sphere (via the stereographic map). The n-sphere can't have a boundary, since it's the boundary of the (n+1)-ball.

Comment: @mastrok Even if that weren't the case, to apply Stokes' theorem you need k-forms with *compact support*, and you need a smooth manifold. A 1-form is the dual of a vector, if it blows up it means something is wrong with the tangent space at that point, meaning the manifold isn't locally $\mathbb R^n$ there. So if 'good coorinates' are picked, there shouldn't be a problem with forms that aren't pathological. Check this paper out for integration of forms with singularities: http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~charles.torossian/Stokes_poles.pdf

Comment: @mastrok The smoothness and compact support might seem too much to ask, but it's really connected to the existence of partitions of unity, which are smooth and w/ compact support, which play a big role in the proof of the theorem.

Comment: @krvolok, you replies are really useful to me, I want to know more. The stereograpgic map from $R^n$ to $S^{n+1}$ is a good example to illustrate the singularity at the north pole looks like the singularities at $\infty$. That point is treated like the boundary of $S^{n+1}$, is that right? If not, how do we apply divergence theorem in simple cartesian coordinate? Could you please explain "So if 'good coorinates' are picked, ..." a bit? What is compact support? Can you simply explain why treating singular points as boundaries are wrong?

Comment: @user260822 You can transition into spherical coorinates via a map $h:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$, $h: (x,y,z)\mapsto (r \sin\theta \sin\phi, r \sin\theta \cos\phi, r \cos \theta).$ It induces a pullback on the form, which really isn't much more than a change of coordinates. In these coordinates, we write
$h^* \mathrm d f = (f_z \cos\theta + f_y \cos\phi\sin\theta+f_x\sin\theta\sin\phi)\mathrm d r + r(f_x \cos\theta\sin\phi+f_y\cos\theta\cos\phi - f_z\sin\theta)\mathrm d \theta + r\sin\theta (f_x\cos\phi - f_y\sin\phi)\mathrm d \phi.$

Comment: @user260822 I think you can leave the functions as they are, that you don't need to do $\partial f /\partial x = \partial f\partial r \cdot \partial r\partial x+\dots$, but only need to pre-compose them with the new coorinates, so that e.g. if $f_x = x$, we get just a change of coordinates $f_x = r\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and so on! :)

Comment: @mastrok $S^n$ can't have a boundary, because it's a boundary itself, and a boundary of a boundary is zero (which is a crucial fact, homology theory rests on it). Let $M\stackrel{loc.}\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ mean $M$ is locally $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\partial M \stackrel{loc.}\rightarrow \mathcal H^n$, and consequently  $\partial\partial M \stackrel{loc.}\rightarrow \partial\mathcal H^n$, however $\mathcal H^n \stackrel{loc.}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n-1}$, and so $\partial \partial M \stackrel{loc.}\rightarrow \partial \mathcal H^n\stackrel{loc.}\rightarrow \partial \mathbb R^{n-1} =\varnothing$

Comment: @mastrok Singular points can be treated as 'boundaries', for instance in spherical coorinates the obvious singular point is just $r=0$, so that $\mathrm d r $ vanishes. This is treated by integrating on a chart such that you exclude an $\epsilon$-ball around the origin, and then let $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, for example. However excluding a single point isn't a boundary, since it's locally a puncutred disc and not a half plane.

Comment: @mastrok Support of a let's say real function is $\text{supp} f := f^{-1}(\mathbb R - \{0\})$, that is, the set on which the function doesn't vanish. A function with a compact support vanishes outside a compact set, so that integrating it over $\mathbb R^n$ is always well defined.

Comment: I know that a boundary can't have a boundary and I agree with what you said about $R^n$ as well. What I think is, when the form or function is irregular at some point, we have to treat those points like some boundary. Colloquially, make a small surface surrounding that point and calculate on that surface and then take the limit to shrink the surface to that point. Is that right? My words may not be mathematically precise, I just tell the picture I have in mind, sorry about that.